# Batch file extract everything up to the last occurence of '\'

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have some relative paths such as `\foo\bar\baz.txt` and I need to extract `\foo\bar` but I cannot use `%~p1` because this gives me a path relative to the current directory, which I do not want. Is there a straightforward way to do this?

Comment: Can you use a for loop to split on / characters? I take it this is windows bat files but your example is unixy?

Comment: Fixed paths for clarity.

Comment: As far as I know, the single `~p` modifier always evaluates to an ‘almost’ absolute path, relative only to the current drive, but *not* to the current directory. You could even ‘extract’ the path from a bare name. Just try this and you'll see: `FOR %A IN (abc) DO ECHO %~pA`. Anyway, that example just shows how `~p` may be unsuitable for you if the given path *is* a relative one, because `~p` would expand it to the absolute path.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that is relative about your path is it is relative to the current drive. You can use %~dp1 to get the full absolute path. Another option is to use FOR variable expansion instead of parameter expansion.

```
for %%F in ("\foo\bar\baz.txt") do set myPath="%%~dpF"
```

The solution should always give a full absolute path for any path, including relative paths.